# Plot every column in a data frame as a histogram on one page using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot each column of a data.frame using a histogram on one page.  Here is an example using the sample "diamonds" data set which comes with R:

```
p = list()
for (i in 1:ncol(diamonds)) p[[i]] <- qplot(diamonds[,i], xlab=names(diamonds)[[i]])
do.call(grid.arrange, p)
```

[image]

This does plot all the columns, but the data looks the same in each one.  So, something is clearly wrong.

Is this the right approach for this task?  I'm sure I have some silly syntax somewhere that is assigning the same column data set to each element in the list, but I'm not sure what it is.

Thank you

Comment: cut, color and clarity are not numeric variables, they are factors. How should they be plotted (since a histogram makes little sense in that case)?

Comment: I'll second what joran said, but if you're ok with ignoring things like that, you want to `melt` the data (`reshape2` package) and then plot with `facet_wrap`

Comment: It might still make sense to count the items each category, but this is just an example.  I am completely fine with removing those columns somehow.

Comment: In that case, just follow @Justin's advice (maybe he'll even write it up as an answer...)

Comment: Not sure how to use melt and facet_wrap for this.  melt seems to allow one to choose columns out of a data.frame, but then I'm not sure how to use facet_wrap to plot them.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here you go:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
d <- melt(diamonds[,-c(2:4)])
ggplot(d,aes(x = value)) + 
    facet_wrap(~variable,scales = "free_x") + 
    geom_histogram()
```

[image]

`melt`ing allows us to use the resulting grouping variables (called `variable`) to split the data into groups and plot a histogram for each one. Note the use of `scales = "free_x"` because each of the variables has a markedly different range and scale.

Comment: I also found extremely useful to pass number of rows/columns to the wrapper: `ggplot(d,aes(x = value)) +geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~variable,scales = "free_x", nrow=2)` or 
    `ggplot(d,aes(x = value)) +geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~variable,scales = "free_x", ncol=4)`

Comment: Is there a way to plot the y axis as frequency? I.e. Every y-axis go from 0 to 1 in fixed increments, and each x-axis go from 0 to the maximum value in the data.

Comment: @Sophy Try adding `aes(y = ..ncount..)` inside of the `geom_histogram()` layer.

Comment: has anyone ever tried to set the same increasement on x-axis, I tried scale_x_continuous(breaks=50), it's not working except removing all the lables on x axis.