# Is it possible to plot multiple histograms of the same variable with different scales on one page?

Tags: r

Take this as an example: [Plot every column in a data frame as a histogram on one page using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035834/plot-every-column-in-a-data-frame-as-a-histogram-on-one-page-using-ggplot)

Let's say I want to produce multiple histograms like in that example. Is it possible to do so, but for one variable, with differnet scales? The different scales would be different divisions of the day, like 24h/12h/6h/4h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, using an example of mtcars data:

```
attach(mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(2,2)) #to create plots in 2x2 matrix
hist(mpg) #default histogram
hist(mpg,breaks=24,main="Breaks=24")
hist(mpg,breaks=seq(10,35,by=5),main="Breaks by 5")
hist(mpg,breaks=seq(10,35,by=2),main="Breaks by 2")
```

Output is shown below. Hope this is what you are looking for..
[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply! This is an option to do so, but do you know if it possible to do the same with ggplot?

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer of @Prasanna Kumar and replying to @Hugo Torres, you can use the package "ggpubr" to combine multiple histograms

```
library(ggpubr)
attach(mtcars)
p1<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=30,color="darkblue", fill="lightblue") +  ggtitle("Histogram of mpg (binwidth=30)")
p2<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=10,color="darkblue", fill="lightblue") +  ggtitle("Histogram of mpg (binwidth=10)")
p3<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=7,color="darkblue", fill="lightblue") +  ggtitle("Histogram of mpg (binwidth=7)")
p4<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=5,color="darkblue", fill="lightblue") +  ggtitle("Histogram of mpg (binwidth=5)")
ggarrange(p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

the result would look like:

[image]